# php zend error: no default module defined for this application

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

So I'm using zend framework and I have this code in a file called UrlRouter.php:

```
class UrlRouter extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeStartup($request)
    {
        $url = $request->getRequestUri();

        echo $url;

    }
}
```

and then I have this in my index.php

```
require_once("UrlRouter.php");

$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->registerPlugin(new UrlRouter($this->getRequest()));
$front->dispatch();
```

but then I get the error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Exception' with message 'No default module defined for this application'
```

what did I do wrong?

the controller plugin seems to be doing its job though...it printed the uri properly but then it is followed by that error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because:

- The request didn't have a module name in it; and
- There is no default module set.

This means that querying an URL like:

```
http://path/to/your/app?module=foo
```

...should work. Or you can define a default module:

```
$front->setDefaultModule('foo');
```

Comment: does it matter what 'foo' is? does it have to be an existing module?

Comment: @kamikaze_pilot: Of course, it should be an existing module. But I think that if you have a single module, it can be anything because Zend will look both for "Foo_IndexController" and "IndexController" classes if the requested module is the default. If I remember correctly. That said you should always have a default module set.

Comment: my zend app isn't exactly modular so everything is just the default directory structure (ie. after applications/ we have controllers etc)...how do I specify this setting then...I tried $front->setDefaultModule('default'); didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

If you have the controllers under /application directly, you need to tell them that the controllers directory is application

```
$front->setDefaultControllerDirectory('application')
```